# Starcraft 2 installer in German

Tags: starcraft-2

After the trial, I went onto the website and paid 44 pounds for the full version by digital download.

Now, after waiting 2 days of solid downloading, I go to install Starcraft 2 and its in German.

What do I do?

Comment: What's your system locale and language?  Which region did you select for the download?

Comment: The installer might be in German, since it might dynamically switch to the current locale of your system, but if you have downloaded the English version, the game will run in English. Have you tried installing the game completely? Don't worry, you can uninstall and reinstall another language anytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not the only person who's had this happen: there are other people on the [SC2 forums](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2037774020) who've had this problem. Here is the response from Blizzard customer service:

> I'm afraid there are no language packs. :( With StarCraft II you need to download the full client in the language of your choice. The English language client is also available from account management though, you just need to specify the language before starting your download.

So it sounds like you'll have to download the full version again, only in English this time.  Make sure you confirm the language, though, and take note of what this person said later in the thread. This is talking about the starter edition rather than the full version, but it sounds like the same sort of thing will apply to your situation.

> Hi. Just wanted to say that the same thing happend to me - I DL the german version of the starter edition SC2 installer and no, the web page was in English and it said FULL GAME CLIENT in English but then in very small greay letters it said Deutsch (german). I do take part of the blame here for not checking the default language as german but when your country is not Germany it should default to English even if D comes before E in the alphabeth. 
>   So after DL the 7 GB on the very slow Blizzard Downloader (6 hours) I find I had to do it all over again for the English version. 
>   I have no DL limits to my Internet so it was just a matter of waiting and I can't really complain about something that was free but it didn't leave a good first impression. But I love the game and have since gotten the full version and I'm happily playing the game so no harm done.